# Get userid in ms windows for uid and gid mapping

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, uid

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7-cli-alpine3.9

ARG USERID=1000
ARG GROUPID=1000

RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash bash-completion bash-doc &&\
    addgroup -g ${GROUPID} developer &&\
    mkdir -p /home/developer/code &&\
    adduser -D -u ${USERID} -G developer -h /home/developer -s /bin/bash developer &&\
    chown developer:developer -R /home/developer/code &&\
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', '/tmp/composer-setup.php');"&&\
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" &&\
    php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer &&\
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" &&\
    chmod +x /bin/composer

VOLUME /home/developer/code
WORKDIR /home/developer/code
USER developer

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

And I can build it via the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        USERID: $USERID
        GROUPID: $GROUPID
    image: 'pcmagas/rover_php'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - './:/home/developer/code'
```

So via providing the values of `$USERID` and `$GROUPID` via a `.env` file each developer can build a custom, tailor-made image for its GNU/Linux local user running the image into his/her computer. Also, he/she can get the user and group id via the following GNU/Linux commands:

```
id -u # For user id
id -g # For group id
```

But on Microsoft windows how I can get the correct user and group id in order to map correctly the user id and group id located inside the image with the one located outside?

Comment: Do you just need the Windows equivalent or the exact same values?

Comment: The windows equivalent commands of getting user and group id in case that this docker image is running unchanged into ms windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows users belong to multiple groups, not a specific group. A user token technically has a `TokenPrimaryGroup` property that is probably there to provide some sort of UNIX compatibility but I don't think Windows comes with a tool to print this SID.

You can get the users SID (SecurityID) with whoami.exe on Vista+:

Batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%A in ('WhoAmI /USER /FO LIST') do @if /I "%%~A" == "SID" echo %%B
```

Interactive cmd.exe:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %A in ('WhoAmI /USER /FO LIST') do @if /I "%~A" == "SID" echo %B
```

A user SID identifies a user on a specific machine or domain. The last part of the SID (the RID) is the unique user part on that machine/domain.

If you absolutely need "a group" you can parse the output of `WHOAMI /GROUPS /FO LIST` and look for `S-1-5-32-544` (Administrators) without **deny only**! If it is present the user is an Administrator and if not they are probably just a user (`S-1-5-32-545`). You can also take a look at [how Samba maps groups](https://www.samba.org/~ab/output/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/groupmapping.html).

Comment: So GNU/Linux userid = SID and GNU/LINUX group  groupid = SID as well?

Comment: Yes, SID strings (S-1-...) identify users, groups and machines. Some SIDs are constant (Administrator and User groups (S-1-5-...)) and some are unique (machines and domains).

Comment: Also somehow I need to make it as an integer. AFAIK Useris in Unix are Unsigned integers as well.

Comment: Well, SIDs are not integers, they are at least 10 bytes (and that is ignoring the version). The user RID (the number after the last dash) is only unique on a specific machine. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/security-identifiers and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier